# How to make a reverb sound like this?

Tags: reverb, fl-studio, convolution-reverb

I am using FL Studio and I have tried reverbs and impulse responses, but I just can't seem to get a similar result. Many of the impulse responses sound too muffled or harsh. Is there any way to achieve a similar reverb?

https://disconscious.bandcamp.com/track/mattress-store-3
https://disconscious.bandcamp.com/track/elevator-down-4